# For-loop of a specified size in shell behavoir

Tags: shell, for-loop, terminal

I'm trying to do a seemingly easy thing: a script that takes a variable from the command line ($1) and uses this as the length of the for loop. So if the command is run.sh in terminal:

```
run.sh 5
```

will run the for loop 5 times. This is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {1..$1};do
 echo $i
done
```

But the only output I receive is:

```
{1..5}
```

How can I solve this?

*Note: I'm a total beginner in bash/shell scripting.*

Comment: I solved it with help from a colleague but don't have rep enough to already answer my own question. Will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you really using the bash shell. Not all shells (especially the true /bin/sh (bourne) ) support that feature. To disambiguate your situation, use

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the top of your script.

One solution is to use

```
for i in $(eval echo  {1..$1} ); do echo $i; done
```

`eval` says, "for the current command string, in this case `echo ${1..$1}`, don't execute the command yet, re-evaluate the complete command line for any expandable variables."

If you system has the `seq` cmd, then you can rewrite this as

```
for i in $(seq 1 $1 ); do echo $i; done
```

`seq` is short for sequence, and can take any starting and ending number, and an optional 'skip by' factor, sa `seq 0 5 100` will count by 5's to 100.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! A colleague helped me solve it by doing this: `for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++))`, which worked. Your solution seems more sophisticated and I'm eager to try it.

Comment: Hm... yes, I wish I had thought of that, as that is the least process intensive solution. Anything that requires `$(...)` is starting an extra bash process just to process 1 command (maybe more), so it's more expensive on CPU and time. If this is a one off, it doesn't matter, if your loop will be run millions of times for years going forward, then `((i=1;i<=$1;i++))` is the definite winner ;-) ! Good luck.

Comment: The problem is the brace expansion happens too early for the original code to work.  The '..' tries and fails before '$1' is expanded.  shellter's solution works because the 'eval' passes the string you need before '..' expansion.